# In the novels, what happens to the Doctor and the rest of the Voyager crew after they return home?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-eu, star-trek-emh

Voyager was a great show with a terrible ending.  Basically the entire show revolved around the characters getting home, but when they finally do the credits roll five seconds later.  So I wonder if the novels have any details about what happens to the Voyager characters after they return to the Federation.

Does the Doctor ever gain his freedom, or the freedom of holograms?

Does Paris ever make up with his father?

What about any of the rest of them?

Comment: “What happens to the Doctor” — “end program”.

Comment: "Voyager was a great show with a terrible ending." There are many who would disagree with the first part of that statement.

Comment: And many who would disagree with the second!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek%3a_Voyager):

> Book relaunch
>
> In the wake of Pocket Books's Deep
>   Space Nine relaunch novel series,
>   which features stories placed after
>   the end of Star Trek: Deep Space Nine,
>   a similar relaunch was planned for
>   Voyager. The novels take place after
>   the series' conclusion. In the
>   relaunch, several characters are
>   reassigned while others are promoted
>   but stay aboard Voyager; these changes
>   include Janeway's promotion to
>   admiral, Chakotay becoming captain of
>   Voyager, Tuvok leaving the ship to
>   serve under William Riker, and Tom
>   Paris' promotion to First Officer. The
>   series also introduces several new
>   characters.
>
> The series began with Homecoming and
>   The Farther Shore in 2003, a direct
>   sequel to the show's finale, Endgame.
>   These were followed in 2004 by Spirit
>   Walk: Old Wounds and Spirit Walk:
>   Enemy of My Enemy. Under the direction
>   of a new author, 2009 brought forth
>   two more additions to the series: Full
>   Circle and Unworthy . Other novels –
>   some set during the relaunch period,
>   others during the show's TV run—have
>   been published.

Comment: So what happens to The Doctor and his slave miner brethren?

Comment: I dunno, read the books? Wait for answers from others?

Comment: My bad, I just assumed you knew

Comment: I never quite got over the fact that Janeway got protomoted before Picard.

Comment: @Henrik - I think Picard took Kirk's advice to heart:  "Well, let me tell you something- don't. Don't let them promote you. Don't let them transfer you. Don't let anything take you off the bridge of that ship. Because while you're there, you can make a difference".  On the other hand Janeway was probably thinking she could stay safely at home as an Admiral...

Comment: -1 the answer doesn't address two of the points in the question and just quotes direct from Wikipedia. A good answer should at least try to summarise Wikipedia so SE is something for than a link to a wiki.

Comment: @Pureferret please notice that this is one of the earliest questions on SFF.SE and predates the current rules. Part of the process of this site was to establish the rules through questions like this. What worked, what didn't. If you want, feel free to edit this answer.

Comment: @DampeS8N I'd love to but I don't know enough about the subject. Do you?

Comment: @Pureferret When our conversation started here, I was the moderator. Now you are and this conversation looks really strange.

Comment: Agreed! Looks strange.

Answer (score 4):

If I remember correctly, the Doctor's fights for freedom and rights influenced his miner copies. It's possible he went on to help them more. I also remember an episode where he and another experimental EMH take over a prototype Starfleet vessel. I don't think he would give up medicine, so he'd probably have gone on an done more research.

Comment: If you believe the future Janeway, he continues in medicine and creates several innovative implants, which allow psychic control of starships.  (according to one of the episodes, where future versions of the crew are seen, maybe even endgame)

Comment: True, I forgot about that one. Wasn't she using some of those implants (or maybe it was someone else?)

Comment: @Teknophilia - Yes, future Janeway had the implant that allowed her to pilot her ship telepathically

Answer (score 4):

I don't know much about the vast Expanded Universe of the novels, but both in *[Star Trek: Nemesis](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Nemesis)* movie and in its [novelization](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Nemesis), we see that Kathryn Janeway was promoted to Vice Admiral, while she orders Captain Picard to a mission to Romulus to meet the new Praetor, Shinzon.